# How to "deep stop" a process?

Tags: bash

I have a long running python script that keeps getting interrupted by battery issues or my own stupidity. I can use (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>) to stop the process and then `fg` to restart it, but as far as I can tell that will only work if I am in the same session and it hasn't been logged out.

Is there a way to deep stop the process so I can restart it at a later time after a logout without having to start from the beginning?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use **screen**, a terminal multiplexer, to solve this problem:

1. Install screen from terminal:
   `sudo apt-get install screen`
2. Start screen with command `screen`
3. You will see an informative message, press Space until you see a terminal prompt
4. Start your python script
5. Detach from the screen instance by pressing **Ctrl+A** and the **D** button.
6. You will see a message on your previous prompt:
   `[detached from 19836.pts-3.ubuntu]`
7. You are successfully detached, you can log out or do whatever you want (unless you power down the machine or kill the process).

When you want to re-attach to your previous screen session, just type `screen -r` in a terminal. You will see your python script that is still working.

You con find further documentation on the [Ubuntu Wiki - Screen](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Screen)